# Select original values inside a Mysql transaction

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

I need to know what values have been changed in a transaction just before to commit the changes. Is it possible to get the original values (not the uncommited values?). For example (fictional code):

```
try {
    $pdo->beginTransaction();
    $pdo->exec('UPDATE items SET name = :name, text = :text WHERE id = :id', $newData);

    //If the update was fine:
    $oldData = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM items WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1', array(':id' => $newData['id']);

    $diff = array_diff_assoc($newData, $oldData);

    echo 'Item was update successfully with new values in '.implode(', ', array_keys($diff));

    $pdo->commit();

} catch (Exception $E) {
    echo 'something is wrown';

    $pdo->rollBack();
}
```

On select data in a transaction, this data is the changed data, not the original data. Is there any option in mysql to skip this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside transaction everything works as if the changes was made at the moment of sending q query. Your only way around that is to:

- start transaction,
- SELECT values you need,
- save them in PHP variable,
- preform your work,
- SELECT again,
- compare,
- commit or not.

And if you only need to test if update was successful, simply catching error is enough already.

Comment: Ok, the problem is that I don't need always this type of feature (It depends of the callback of each query), so I didn't want to make this select always just for some specific cases.

Comment: @OscarOtero MySQL does not keep "original values" in any accessible place I know of. You could try to open additional connection to test current values, but without any warranty they were not altered by other queries, unrelated to your transaction (or simply concurrent instance of it).